# What is the effect of permissions on external drives?

Tags: security, external-disk, permission, unix

I've set the permissions on files on my removable external drives in ways that seem to make sense to preserve some degree of security. For example, for files that only I should have access to, I've only myself any access rights

```
-rw-------@   1 MyName  staff  ... File1
```

while for others, that I want other users of my machine to have access to, I've expanded these access rights a bit

```
-rw-r-----@   1 MyName  staff  ... File2
```

This behaves as I intend on my machine; but what happens if the drive is plugged into a different machine? Does anyone on the `staff` group there have read access to `File2` and none to `File`? Would anyone who was given the user name `MyName` on that machine have full access to both files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone with the same user ID as you have on your main machine will be able to read the disk. The, usually hidden, user Ids start at 501 and increase. If you are not the first user on a machine you will not be able to read the contents of the drive.

I've gone round and round with this. If you need a secure drive then you need to encrypt it with a password. There are ways to do this using the tools built into Mountain Lion, or you can use a third party solution like [True Crypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).

Comment: So its not the name, but the ID that will give access. Correct? For example, on another Mac, where `staff` has the same ID by default, all members of `staff` there will have the same access they have on my machine, while any user there who happens to have my user ID, *regardless of what their user name is*, will have the same access I have.

Comment: That is correct. It's a lousy way of doing things, but it's what we've got.

Comment: Yes, I've had to do other things to secure the drives, but was wondering if there was anything useful that the permissions were doing to. Clearly not. Presumably the same is true for network access?

Comment: Yeah, it's all based on the same 60's version of privacy.